# What is the algebraic equation of the following flow?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, vector-fields

I want to plot the following flow in math softwares but I don't know its algebraic equation! Any hint would be greatly appreciated. (image from [Milnor's Topology from differential viewpoint](https://books.google.com/books/about/Topology_from_the_Differentiable_Viewpoi.html?id=BaQYYJp84cYC))

[image]

**Edited:** A function with two asymptotic line (at least, a function with one slanted and one horizontal asymptotic line), and similar to above image, suffices. e.g. A function with four connected components and slant asymptotic $y=-x$ and horizontal asymptotic $y=0$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe such an equation exists?

Comment: You are right. but I don't want its flow really. A function with two asymptotic line, and similar to above image, suffices.

Comment: Just need to plot the level curves near a saddle point for a function. By trial and error, you should find one easily. A standard ones are $x^2-y^2+c=0$. You can twist it by deforming $x,y$ by a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: It looks like a warped version of $dx/dt=-x, dy/dt=y$